# USAMO 1973 (Simultaneous Equations)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Determine all the roots, real or complex, of the system of simultaneous equations [(USAMO 1973/4)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1973_USAMO_Problems/Problem_4)
> $$x+y+z=3$$
> $$x^2+y^2+z^2=3$$
> $$x^3+y^3+z^3=3$$

Multiply equation I by 2 and subtract it from Equation II:
$$x^2-2x+y^2-2y+z^2-2z=-3$$

Complete the square for all three variables:
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2=0$$

Since the RHS is zero, and the LHS has only perfect squares, by the trivial inequality, we must have:
$$(x-1)^2=0\Rightarrow x=1$$
$$(y-1)^2\Rightarrow y=1$$
$$(z-1)^2=0\Rightarrow z=1$$

Hence, the only solution for Equations I and II is
$$x=y=z=1$$

This satisfies Equation III as well. And hence, this is also the only solution to the overall system of equations.

1.
Would this be enough to get full marks?
Anything missing, or needed to be added?

2.
The complex roots is neither needed nor used anywhere. This was just used to (artificially?)  increase the "complexity" of the problem. Is this correct.

Comment: Why must $ ( x - 1 ) ^2 + (y-1)^2  + (z-1)^2 = 0 $ imply that all values are 0? In particular, we have a solution like $ x = 1 + i, y = 1, z = 0 $.    (You are incorrectly assuming that $x-1$ is a real value. This is where "complex roots" come in. Hence, this is worth 0 points.)

Comment: Got it. Is there any way of fixing this? Or does the approach need to be changed entirely?

Comment: This approach (of trying to use inequalities on complex numbers) isn't likely to work, because you don't have inequalities on complex numbers, or any way to compare them. At the most, you can try to get to the absolute value, but it's not easy to force out (say) $|xyz|^2 = xyz\bar{xyz}$.

Comment: Let me try using cubic polynomials.

Comment: Major hint in white font: $\color{white}{\text{Vieta's formula}}$. Highlight it to read.

Comment: In real numbers $\;\frac{x+y+z}{3}=\sqrt\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3} \implies x=y=z\;$ by the [RMS-AM](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) inequality, for a shortcut. But of course that doesn't cover the case of complex roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(x+y+z)^2=9=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)\implies xy+yz+zx=3$$
$$(x+y+z)^3=27=6xyz+3(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(x^3+y^3+z^3)=6xyz+27-6\implies xyz=1$$
Hence by Viète's formulas $x,y,z$ are the roots of $t^3-3t^2+3t-1=(t-1)^3$, so $x=y=z=1$ is the only solution.

Note that Viète's formulas are valid even in the complex plane; the specification of "complex" in the question precludes using real-line tricks like the $x^2\ge0$ inequality in your attempt.

Comment: Side note: Newton's identities give us a (essentially) one-line solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Newton's Identities solution?

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments,

1. This solution is completely wrong and worth 0 points. You incorrectly assumed that $x-1, y-1, z-1$ are real numbers.
2. This is incorrect. Solving for "real roots" is very different from solving for "complex roots".

---

**Claim:** With $n$(=3 in this case) variables, Newton's identities tell us that the first $n$ power sums uniquely determine the $n$ elementary symmetric polynomials, which uniquely determines the  complex $x_i$ (up to permutation) via Vieta's formula.

**One idea/line solution:** Hence, this system has a unique solution (up to permutation of $x, y, z$), which we observe to be $(1, 1, 1)$.
Thus there is only 1 complex solution.

---

I leave it to you to verify the claim and unpack this statement.
It uses more machinery than is necessary to solve this problem, but showcases the underlying mathematics, which is why this is my favorite approach. I'm not saying that one approach is better than the other.
Parcly's solution does the work of finding these elementary symmetric polynomials, while I avoid calculating them by guessing the unique solution.
Parcly's approach is guaranteed to obtain the solution, while mine requires some luck.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut True that. In such cases (in contest math), it's understood to be "unique up to permutation", but let me make that explicit.

Answer (score 4):

The nicer solutions have been posted already, so here is a different one, just for fun.

Moving the constant terms $\,3\,$ to the LHS, distributing and factoring, the system can be written as:

$$
\begin{cases}
  (x-1) & +\; (y-1) & +\; (z-1) & = 0 \\
  (x-1) \cdot (x+1) & +\; (y-1) \cdot (y+1) & +\; (z-1) \cdot (z+1) & = 0 \\
  (x-1) \cdot (x^2+x+1) & +\; (y-1) \cdot (y^2+y+1) & +\; (z-1) \cdot (z^2+z+1) & = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Considering this as a linear system in $\,x-1,y-1,z-1\,$ its determinant is:

$$
\left| 
\begin{matrix}
\;1 \;&\; 1 \;&\; 1 \; \\
\;x+1 \;&\; y+1 \;&\; z+1 \; \\
\;x^2+x+1 \;&\; y^2+y+1 \;&\; z^2+z+1 \; \\
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$

After the obvious manipulations, this reduces to a [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) in variables $\,x,y,z\,$, which is non-zero iff all variables are different. But that case leads to the contradiction that the trivial solution $\,x-1=y-1=z-1=0\,$ has all variables equal. So the determinant must be $\,0\,$ i.e. two of the variables be equal. Assuming $\,x=y\,$ for example, it is straightforward to verify that the only solution is, again, $\,x=y=z=1\,$.

Comment: +1 Nice. This is a restatement of mine solution presented in different terminology. IE 1) Have to guess the solution, 2) The vandermonde determinant observation is a special case of "newton's identities determine a unique solution when the variables are distinct".    $\quad$ Unfortunately, 2) is weaker than my claim. So, if you're willing, can you elaborate on how we can deal with repeated roots  in the general case? IE If the power sums were $4, 6, 10$ corresponding to $(1, 1, 2)$, can we still push through your approach?

Comment: @CalvinLin Don't think the trick extends naturally to cases where the roots are different. It might be possible to brute-force it somehow, though that would probably become equivalent to a disguised [resultant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B%284-x-y%29%5E2-6%2C+x%5E3%2By%5E3%2B%284-x-y%29%5E3-10%2C++y+%29). Which would be an overkill here, where the direct answer is a one-liner, as you posted (+1).

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess/conclusion too.  $\quad$ The method I had for continuing, is that once we do a change of variables to get $\sum x_i ^k = 0$, from which $\prod x_i = 0$ (which is essentially Newton's identities, so not a significantly different approach), so one of them is 0, and then induct on the number of terms.