# Number of solutions to $x+y+z=x^2+y^2+z^2=x^3+y^3+z^3=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Determine all the roots, real or complex, of the system of simultaneous equations [(USAMO 1973/4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4239755/240768)
> $$x+y+z=3$$
> $$x^2+y^2+z^2=3$$
> $$x^3+y^3+z^3=3$$

Using [exactly the same approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4239755/240768) as this answer here:
$$x+y+z=3$$
$$xy+yz+zx=3$$
$$xyz=1$$

And we then conclude that these are the roots of a cubic polynomial. This restricts the maximum number of solutions to $3$.

How do we know or show that the number of solutions is maximum $3$?

Comment: The maximum number of solution (where the initial equations could have any value) is $3! = 6$ (not just 3). Again, this follows from my answer as the solutions are determined up to permutation. EG $x+y+z = 6, x^2+y^2+z^2 = 14, x^3+y^3+z^3 = 36$ has the 6 solutions arising from permutations of $(1, 2, 3)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin should this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel It's not really a duplicate to me, since it's asking a very different question. Someone who understands your/mine solution could answer this question properly. However, I'm not certain about OP's mathematical ability (in fully comprehending what the solutions are getting at), esp looking at questions that they've been asking.

Comment: For the 2-variable case $\,x+y=a, x^2+y^2=b\,$, could you clarify how you count the "*maximum number of solutions*", and how you relate that to the fact that a quadratic has two roots (counting multiplicities).

Comment: $x^2+y^2+2xy=a^2 \Rightarrow xy=\frac{a^2-b}{2}$

Then $x, y$  are the roots of the quadratic $z^2-az+\frac{a^2-b}{2}$.

If the roots of the above quadratic are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then we can have:
$(x,y)=(\alpha,\beta),(\beta,\alpha)$.

And these are the only possible solutions to $x$ and $y$. Is this logic correct?

Comment: @dxiv If I consider geometrically then x+y is a line, and x^2+y^2 is a circle. The solution to this will be 2 intersections (secant), 1 intersection (tangent), or no intersections. Secant corresponds to two distinct roots, tangent corresponds to a repeated root, and no intersections corresponds to two complex roots.

Comment: @Starlight If you consider the max number to be $\,2=2!\,$ in the 2-variable case, then it should be $\,6=3!\,$ in the 3-variable case, by the exact same logic - as noted in the top comment above.

Comment: I think I missed the permutations part of it. When I originally wrote 3, I meant 3 distinct roots/solutions (without permutations), which translates to a maximum of 6 ordered triplets $x,y,z$ when you consider permutations.

Essentially, the logic is that since these are the roots of a cubic, you have then found all possible solutions.

IF you extend this, the four Vieta's Formulas for a  biquadratic will give you the 4!=24 possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of algebra states that any polynomial will have the same number of roots as the degree of the polynomial (counting repeated roots).

Looking at the last set of equations, we can use Viète's formulas to find the cubic which solves the original set of equations.

$x + y + z = \frac{-b}{a}$, $xy + xz + yz = \frac{c}{a}$, $xyz = \frac{-d}{a}$, therefore plugging in the values from the last set of equations gives you: $3a = -b, 3a = c, a = -d$.

Knowing that the general form of a cubic is $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ and using the relations, the cubic used to solve the last set of equations is $ax^3-3ax^2+3a-a=0$. Since $a \neq 0$, $x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 = 0$.

Therefore, the cubic is guaranteed to have $3$ roots (including repeated roots) because of the fundamental theorem of algebra and hence, the last set of equations.